# Can we turn on the iphone's number keyboard WITHOUT using type=number?

Tags: iphone, html

I'm making a webapp, and I'd like an input field to show the Iphone's number keypad.
I understand that `type=number` will make the keypad show the way I'd like.

The trouble is that `type=number` does not support placeholder text. So if I would like this:

Expiration Date:
[eg: 2010]

I can not get it to work, and also show the right keyboard.

Is there a way to force the iPhone keyboard into number mode without using the number input type?

Comment: Another use case for this: If i use type=number, I can't set the size of the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Placeholder seems to work (in both Safari on my Mac as Mobile Safari on my iPhone; [compatibility list](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#placeholder)).

```
<input type="number" placeholder="2010">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XPL48/

Otherwise, use JavaScript to create a placeholder, e.g. this jQuery plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/placeholder.

Comment: I don't know how I missed this. I KNOW I tested it. Maybe I didn't refresh hard enough? I guess I just assumed it had a problem with me putting letters (ABC) in a number (123) input placeholder. Oops. Sorry and thanks, Alec.